# text change inHTML textarea automatically when ever there is a input change in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

It is working perfectly, but onmouseover, its changing only once. How can onmouseover works multiple times? I mean when ever text arrays changed

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script> 
function myFunction() 
{ 
var i; 
var text = ["No Change", "No Change", "Update1", "No Change", "Update2"]; 
text2=""; 
for (i=0; i<5; i++) 
{ 
if(text[i]=="No Change") 
{ 
continue; 
} 
else 
{ 
text2 = text2+text[i]+"\n"; 
} 
} 
document.getElementById("myTextarea").value = text2;
 }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <textarea id="myTextarea" onmouseover="myFunction()" cols="100" style="color:blue;" readonly> No change </textarea> 
</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: try to provide code please...no only an idea...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide the code of what you have tried so far and place it within your question body. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve as your question is written, it is hard to understand what you want. A demo (even when it's broken) will help us to get the idea.

Comment: Apologies, I am very new to html, javascript & css.

Comment: It's not easy to write a good question. But you will have to put in a lot of more efford to get answers. We know nothing about your project. Try to create a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/
Insert some html and your current javascript, that builds the array posted. Otherwise i really don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: <html> <head> <script> function myFunction() { var i; var text = ["No Change", "No Change", "Update1", "No Change", "Update2"]; text2=""; for (i=0; i<5; i++) { if(text[i]=="No Change") { continue; } else { text2 = text2+text[i]+"\n"; } } document.getElementById("myTextarea").value = text2; } </script> </head> <body> <textarea id="myTextarea" onmouseover="myFunction()" cols="100" style="color:blue;" readonly> No change </textarea> </body> </html> It is working perfectly, but onmouseover, its changing only once. How can onmouseover works multiple times? I mean when ever text arrays changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully I understood your question properly. I slightly tweaked your original code to clean it up, so now every time `checkText()` is called it will write any values that aren't "No Change" to the textarea.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        var text = ["No Change", "No Change", "Update1", "No Change", "Update2"]; 
        var text2=""; //don't forget to declare variables
        function checkText() {
            var flag = 0;
            for (var i=0; i<text.length; i++) { //unnecessary to declare i outside of loop if not used elsewhere
                if(text[i]!="No Change") { 
                    text2 += text[i] + " "; //A simpler way of doing "text = text + something" | "\n" is new line
                    flag = 1;
                } 
            } 
            if (flag == 1) {
                document.getElementById("myTextarea").value = text2;
            } else {
                document.getElementById("myTextarea").value = "No change";
            }
        }
        </script>
    <head>
    <body>
    <textarea id="myTextarea" cols="100" readonly> No change </textarea>
    <button onClick="checkText()">Check Text</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

In my example the code only runs on the click of a button, but if you would like it to run at an interval, every second for example, read about the setInterval() function [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp).

Just a side note: remember to declare variables, and only declare them at the scope you need them (i.e. if you only need them within a for-loop, declare them within the for-loop).

Comment: Hi @grahamhoyes,
IT is working well, but appending the text in textarea, 
upon Onsubmit,  I would like to clear the text area and enter the new text. Could you please help me on this?

Comment: @SunilM What do you mean by that? In my code, the text area is only used for outputting response, the original text comes from the array `text`.

Comment: Hi, I am getting output as 
Update1 Update2 Update1 Update2 Update1 Update2
if I click "Check Text" button.

Comment: @SunilM I think I understand what you are saying. My code just appends on anything that is different to the textarea. If you would like it to just write the latest one to the textarea and overwrite any previous flags, change line 10 of my code to be `text2 = text[i];`

Answer (score 1):

It is little bit difficult to understand where you got stuck without seeing your code, but from your description, I developed this code. Check this and I hope it will help you.

```
<html>

<body>

    <input type="text" id="a[0]" value="No Change"><br>
    <input type="text" id="a[1]" value="No Change"><br>
    <input type="text" id="a[2]" value="No Change"><br>
    <input type="text" id="a[3]" value="No Change"><br>
    <input type="text" id="a[4]" value="No Change"><br>
    <input type="text" id="a[5]" value="No Change"><br>
    <input type="text" id="a[6]" value="No Change"><br>
    <input type="text" id="a[7]" value="No Change"><br>
    <input type="text" id="a[8]" value="No Change"><br>
    <input type="text" id="a[9]" value="No Change"><br><br>

    <input type="button" onclick="change_text_area()" value="Check Now" /><br><br>

    <textarea id="text_area" rows="4" cols="50" ></textarea>


    <!-- JAVASCRIPT CODE BEGINS -->

    <script>

    function change_text_area()
    {
        var flag=0;
        var str="";
         for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
         { 
                var inp=document.getElementById("a["+i+"]").value;
                if(inp!="No Change")
                {
                    str=str+" "+inp;
                    flag=1;
                }   
         }

        if(flag==1)
        {
            document.getElementById("text_area").value=str;
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("text_area").value="No Change";
        }
   }
  </script>

  <!-- JAVASCRIPT CODE ENDS -->

</body>
```

Comment: <html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var i;
var text = ["No Change", "No Change", "Update1", "No Change", "Update2"];
text2="";
for (i=0; i<5; i++)
{
if(text[i]=="No Change")
{
continue;
}
else
{
    text2 = text2+text[i]+"\n";
}
}
document.getElementById("myTextarea").value = text2;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="myTextarea" onmouseover="myFunction()" cols="100" style="color:blue;" readonly>
No change
</textarea>
</body>
</html>

It is working perfectly, but onmouseover, its changing only once. How can onmouseover works multiple times? I mean when ever text arrays changed

Comment: I request you to please provide the code in a formatted manner.
It is very difficult to read.

Comment: You can use onmouseout() to recall the Function.

Comment: Hi Posted the code in main question, As I am not aware how to post the code in proper way in the comment, apologies for the trouble...

Comment: As you have predefined the values in your code and there is no way to change the text when the code is running, so that is why when the mouse hovers over the textarea first time, it checks the input values and change the textbox. When you again hovers over the textarea, it again checks the input values, but as the values are same everytime, mouse hovering doesnt bring any change after first time.

Comment: Hi,
even onmouseout also working only once, It will be great help if it works every time. bec input values can change at any point of time.
Is there anway to work all the time?